# Umbraco - Get All tags used in a node/group

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-tags

I have used `GetTags()` method under `umbraco.cms.businesslogic.Tags.Tag` to get all tags under a group or node.

```
var tags = umbraco.cms.businesslogic.Tags.Tag.GetTags("default");
```

But with `umbraco.cms.businesslogic.Tags.Tag` being obsolete now, is there any other better alternative?

Also, does the new library offer tag-based querying of nodes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay, So Umbraco 7 has the new **[`TagService`](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/48688-TagService-Umbraco-7)** library to deal with tags.

To get all Tags used,

```
var service = UmbracoContext.Application.Services.TagService;
var blogTags = service.GetAllTags("default");
```

---

To get specific tag content `GetTaggedContentByTag()` is the method exposed,

```
var sports = service.TagService.GetTaggedContentByTag("Gaming");
```

It returns the *TaggedEntity* list and the *TaggedEntity* object with *EntityId* property.

**[Source](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/7.1.5/src/Umbraco.Core/Services/TagService.cs)** <sub>Courtesy : Jimbo Jones</sub>

Comment: Its also useful to take a look at the new Tag Service: https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/7.1.5/src/Umbraco.Core/Services/TagService.cs

Comment: You should use Umbraco Helper for frontend, services don't use the cache and query the DB directly..

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to call tag service.

In umbraco 7 you can use this:

```
var tags = Umbraco.TagQuery.GetAllTags();
```

or

```
var tags = Umbraco.TagQuery.GetAllTags(group);
```

And you can use

```
var mycontents = Umbraco.TagQuery.GetContentByTag("mytag")
```

To fetch your data

Answer (score 1):

I've found limitations with the TagService and have used the following to get a list of tags from a specific set of nodes. Just querying the tags by the group has not worked for me.

```
var pages = parentpage.Children;   
var allNodesWithTags = pages.Where("tags != \"\"");

List<string> taglist = new List<string>();      
foreach (var node in allNodesWithTags)
{
    taglist.AddRange(node.tags.ToString().Split(','));
}

taglist = taglist.OrderBy(q => q).ToList();
```

It is then simple to output a list of tags from the child nodes:

```
@foreach (string tag in taglist.Distinct())
{
    <li><a href="#" class="">@tag</a></li>
}
```